# Fatal error: Class 'Hours\Minutes\Seconds' not found in my.php line 10

Tags: php, namespaces

I get this error below in **My.php**

> Fatal error: Class 'Hours\Minutes\Seconds' not found in My.php line 10

My.php

```
use Hours\Minutes\Seconds;
class My {
    ...
    Seconds::myfunc(); //line 10
    ...
}
```

---

Seconds.php

```
namespace Hours\Minutes;
class Seconds {
    function myfunc() {...}
}
```

EDIT: autoloader class is created and works fine.

Comment: Are you including/requiring the Seconds.php file? You might want to look into using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)/psr4 so you don't have to think about this btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include your class or create an *autoloader* class

```
use Hours\Minutes\Seconds;

require_once 'Seconds.php'; //Add this line and set right file path

class My {
    ...
    Seconds::myfunc(); //line 10
    ...
}
```